# Child Project reads the Parent property file instead of own property file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

There are 2 spring boot projects. Let's get their names A and B. Project A is using project B.

A - Parent // B  - Child

When I run project A, project B, which I added as a dependency, reads the properties file, which is not correct.

B Project

properties file : application.yml

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class OblspApplication {
}

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.yml")
public class LogSender {
}
```

A Project

properties file : application.yml

```
@EnableEurekaClient
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(OblspApplication.class)
public class ObLoggingServiceApplication {}
```

When I start project A, the property source annotation in the LogSender class reads the property file of project A instead of its own property file.

How can I fix this problem?
Thanks

Comment: `There are 2 spring boot projects` I will not recommend this approach. make `project B` dependency `non spring boot` and inject as library. If both are independent services then use **Inter process Communication**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Project B is a library that Project A depends on. Libraries should not declare it's own properties file as only one property file will be read from the class path. Usually libraries declare beans to be used somewhere else, but is the app that uses those beans that provides some configuration to use those beans in properties file, in your case, Project A.

Take a look at https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/ for a guide that explains this with an example.